# How to create same array of structs from string in pyspark?

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I wrote code that transforms string into array of structs.
I would like to do the same in python. Do you have any clue how can I do it?

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.Column


val df: DataFrame = Seq(
  "adserviceCalculateCpcAlgorithmV1:2;searchProductsDecorator:3;searchOffersDecorator:3;bundlediscounts:5;searchGridType:3"
).toDF("abTests")

display(
  df
    .withColumn("abTestsArr", split($"abTests", ";"))
    .withColumn("abTestsArr", 
      transform(col("abTestsArr"), (c: Column) => {
        struct(
          split(c, ":").getItem(0) as "name",
          split(c, ":").getItem(1) as "group"
        )
      }) 
    )
)
```

Comment: all of these functions are available with similar names and functionality. have you checked out the [doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/functions.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would do the same in Python using lambda expression as the second parameter for [`transform`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.2.0/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.transform.html) function:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df.withColumn(
    "abTestsArr",
    F.transform(
        F.split("abTests", ";"), lambda x: F.struct(
            F.substring_index(x, ":", 1).alias("name"),
            F.substring_index(x, ":", -1).alias("group")
        )
    )
).show(truncate=False)
```

Instead of parsing it yourself, you could also consider using [`str_to_map`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#str_to_map) to get a MapType column then convert into array of structs using `map_entries` function:

```py
df.withColumn(
    "abTestsMap", 
    F.map_entries(F.expr("str_to_map(abTests, ';', ':')"))
).show(truncate=False)
```